# What is the direction of rotation of sphere on plank if a force is applied on the plank?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

Suppose a solid sphere is kept on a rough  plank , and then a horizontal force F is applied on the plank. Then in which direction will the sphere start rolling , given that no slipping takes place , and the plank is not fixed? 
According to me , a pseudo force will act on the sphere opposite in direction to the applied force F , and hence the sphere will roll in the direction opposite to that of the movement of the plank.
Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The plank acts by both a force and a torque on the sphere.

Therefore

- The force changes the sphere momentum to move in direction of the plank motion.
- The torque changes the sphere angular momentum to roll in the opposite direction.

As the result, the sphere is rolling backwards, but the center is moving wrt the plank slower, than is the plank speed, so it still moves with the plank.

The above consider an inertial coordinate system. 
An inertial system is the system where the 2nd Newton motion law F=m.a is valid.

For its validity in accelerating or rotating coordinate (= non inertial) systems, we need formally include nonexistent force ( pseudoforce, fictitious force)

There  are no pseudoforces in inertial systems, as they are fictitious.

Pseudoforces in non inertial (accelerating or rotating) systems are fully addressed by real forces in inertial systems.

If we consider noninertial system, where the plank is in rest, then sure, the pseudoforce and pseudotorque is acting, causing the sphere to roll.

Comment: Are you talking about the pseudo force?

Comment: No, why should be pseudo force even considered ? It would be the case if the  coordinate system would be non inertial, like accelerating or rotating.

Comment: Then would the plank exert force on the sphere because of friction?

Comment: Sure. It was explicitly said there is no slipping.

Comment: But in most real scenarios, the momentum of inertia usually causes slipping, as it rather hesitates to start rolling

Comment: Any body placed in an accelerating car would experience a pseudo force in the backward direction . Then wouldn't the sphere experience a pseudo force in the backward direction as it kept on a plank which is accelerating?

Comment: As I said before in the prior comment. There was not explicitly said we consider coordinate system accelerating with the plank. I consider inertial system, in which the plank is accelerating.

Comment: Sir , can you please explain the difference between inertial and non inertial system in this question?

Comment: And in inertial system how do we account for the pseudo forces?

Comment: Note that at least basic search e.g for Wikipedia terms is highly adviced, before asking questions on SE sites.

Comment: See the answer update.